# CMYK color values to its int equivalent

Tags: c#, int, equivalent, cmyk

I have CMYK color values ( 0, 0.58 ,1 ,0 ) . Now  I have to convert to its Integer equivalent using C# . I think it is possible using Bitwise operator but not sure .

Kindly assist me how can achieve same .

Thanks,
 Pawan

Comment: If you only want to convert them to int, you can use Convert.ToInt32 method. But that would make you lose the precision. Did you maybe think of converting them to RGB colorspace?

Comment: @Legoless no, I think I understood what the OP wanted, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
float c = 0.0;
float y = 0.58;
float m = 1.0;
float k = 0.0;

uint intColor = (uint)(c * 255) << 24;
intColor += (uint)(y * 255) << 16;
intColor += (uint)(m * 255) << 8;
intColor += (uint)(k * 255) << 0;
```

Here `intColor` will be a 32-bit unsigned integer, containing the byte value of the C, Y, M and K components of the color, respectively. To convert back to the components from the integer, simply invert all the operations and their order:

```
float c = ((intColor & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0f;
float y = ((intColor & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0f;
float m = ((intColor & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0f;
float k = ((intColor & 0x000000FF) >> 0) / 255.0f;
```

Comment: Thanks... Can you tell me how to convert from back from int to CMYK equivalent  ?

Comment: @userXXX you keep mentioning this 'equivalent' persistently... But what is it? What do you want, precisely?

Comment: Hello, Suppose I have CMYK color values ( 0, 0.58 ,1 ,0 )  Now i have to convert it into Int and  than later I will have to get from Int values to CMYK values. Here I want back and forth conversion from CMYK to Int and Vice-versa . CMYK represnt the color values.so int also should reprensent the equivalnet color value . yes I want precisely.

Comment: Also, The code above ( for conversion from CMYK to int ) , the OutPut is stored as Uint ... is that correct ... kindly assist me.

Comment: @userXXX I see. Also, I rarely write incorrect answers. In fact, it's better to use an UInt conceptionally - bitwise operations are safer and a color component cannot be negative.

Comment: why work with /255 or /256? CMYK are percentages (2 decimals?)